# Is "centerpoint" one word or two?

Tags: grammar

I see that "centerpoint" has a [definition on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centerpoint) that has to do with the mathematical entity, but I don't see it in online dictionaries.

So which sentence below spells the term correctly? This one:

> Rays of light will burst out from the centerpoint.

or this one:

> Rays of light will burst out from the center point.

I think the admins who closed this question don't understand that there are no opinions involved. I'm only stating what I've observed and asking a question about that.

Comment: I recommend you say it as you have done: as "center point".

Comment: "Centerpoint" is one word, "center point" is two.

Comment: Well yes, I can count. That's not really the question, is it?

Comment: It's weather or not 'centerpoint' can be properly used outside of mathematics.

Comment: @BBaysinger - Depends on which way the wind blows.

Comment: Please include which online dictionaries you have consulted so that we don't duplicate your research. Also, check out the wesbite called OneLook for an easy way to look up  a word in multiple online dictionaries. Note finally that many compound words are spelled with a space but are still considered to be *one word*,  for instance  *home run*.

Comment: I love that some arrogant person voted this down. Like the question was a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: People borrow jargon in daily life all the time. You just have to understand who in the audience will understand. If people aren't familiar with a fairly obscure term, they'll likely think it's a typo.

Answer (score 1):

> Rays of light will burst out from the center <strike>point</strike>.

It's just the *center*, no point.

Outside of mathematics, "centerpoint" is a redundancy because *center* already is defined as a point.

Comment: Right, of course. But I'd say center point is redundant anywhere.....No point is right and I just can't find the point. [caveat: joke]

Comment: However, Ngram finds "centerpoint" to be increasingly common over the past 30-40 years.

Comment: @HotLicks Popular proper noun!

Comment: @Kris - Yeah, maybe half use it as a proper noun, and a quarter appear to be in the mathematical sense.  But a non-trivial number use it as a "real" word.

Answer (score -1):

I would say this dictionary conclusion is wrong, Centerpoint is not redundant because it is commonly used in text.

"Playing up his own baseless election fraud claims (which nearly every GOP senator knows are ludicrous) was a centerpoint of Trump's pitch to the crowd."

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/412810)

Comment: This is a distinct use of *centerpoint* with a metaphorical meaning meaning the central theme of a speech/text/etc, but it's not related to the question which is about a point in space. There's no dispute that *centrepoint* can be one word sometimes, it's in a specific context that we are interested.